# Teams adaptive card wait for respons in Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm trying out adaptive cards in an attempt to integrate warnings through logic apps with teams. the question i'm about to ask is related to having the connector in Logic app wait for an response from the adaptive card in Teams after being sent from the Logic app.

I've managed to create my adaptive card and in that card i have the necessary information and two actions at the bottom that i want my logic app to react on so to speak.

My Adaptive card looks something like this:

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.0",
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Alert - Employee email differences found:",
        "weight": "Bolder",
        "size": "Medium",
        "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
        "spacing": "Medium",
        "maxLines": 0
    },
    {
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "columns": [
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "stretch",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "New Email",
                        "weight": "Bolder"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Test.Person21@mail.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Test.Person22@mail.com"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "stretch",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Old Email",
                        "weight": "Bolder"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Test.Person11@mail.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Test.Person12@mail.com"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "separator": true
    }
],
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Update Now",
        "style": "positive",
        "data": true
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Dismiss",
        "style": "destructive",
        "data": false
    }
]
}
```

[image]

As you can se when i push on "update now" i get the error message saying "there is no backend/app to connect to" (in swedish - "Can't reach application, try again") basically.

So again what i'm trying to do is for the Logic app to wait for the respons.
After the logic app has sen the message it "completes".

So is this possible? If so, how do i get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

while logic apps can send cards to MS Teams they can not listen on actions performed on those cards.

To be able to use card actions you need to have a custom service made that listens and acts on those activities.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Tim! You are right, i managed to track down some information saying just that. I later went on trying out the Adaptive card SDK to see if i could have a bit more control over the Adaptive card itself in terms of connectivity to a custom service but from what i can find-  documentation on this seems to be rare at least on what i'm searching. Do you possibly have anything you know could be helpful to what i'm trying to achieve to share?

Comment: There's various things you can do. 
You really just need a backend service (whatever you prefer) which has a POST endpoint where the cards send their activity to. However using something like this https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-dotnet might also really help.

Comment: Thanks you for the quick answer. As of now i already have my backend service ready with an post endpoint already exposed. Where do i configure the connection between the adaptive card and the backend? I've seen thinks like configuring "connection extensions" for the channels in teams like "webhooks" and such. Or is this done in other ways?

Comment: Actually I'm not 100% sure how to do that with Logic apps involved. Usually you have a bot that is registered via dev.botframework.com this is also where you set the endpoint url. However the usual flow is you send a card from your bot not from within Logic apps. 

As far as i know the best option would be to have logic apps send something to your backend and your backend ultimately sends the card. Or there's something within logic apps to set an endpoint for the card actions but not sure if that exists atm.